# How to run a query in docker container after mariadb has started?

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I am attempting to create a mariadb container, and want to have a SQL script start at the beginning.

**Base Dockerfile**

```
FROM mariadb:10.5.6
# Copy a "creation.sql" script to the container
COPY /sql/* /sql/
```

**Manual Execution Works**

If I wait 10-20 seconds after the container is started, then do a command line `docker exec -it my_container_name mysql -e "source sql/creation.sql;" -uroot -pMyPasswordHere` then the script runs fine. But I would rather have this part of the build or run processes, rather than requiring a manual step and a guess at waiting time.

**RUN - Doesn't work**

I tried using `RUN` in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN mysql -e "source sql/creation.sql;" -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`
```

but it
fails with: *Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket* during the build. I assume this is because the service hasn't started yet.

**CMD - Doesn't work**

I also tried executing creation.sql with mysql using `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, but they seems to fail during the run. An example of CMD solution that should call `mysqld` (matching what's in the [mariadb Dockerfile](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/10.5/Dockerfile)) and then run the sql, but fails when running the container:

```
FROM mariadb:10.5.6
COPY /sql/* /sql/
CMD mysqld && mysql -e "source sql/creation.sql;" -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

**CMD with shell script - Doesn't work**

An example of a script-based solution which also fails:

```
FROM mariadb:10.5.6
COPY /sql/* /sql/
COPY /scripts/* /scripts/
CMD ["./scripts/start.sh"]
```

start.sh:

```sh
exec mysqld
echo "Running start script\n" > start.log
for i in {1..20}
do
    sleep 3
    echo "Attempt $i"
    echo "Attempt $i" &>> start.log
    mysql -e "source sql/creation.sql;" -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD &>> start.log
done
echo "Done" &>> start.log
```

**Is there a simple solution?**

Is there any way to run a SQL script file just with the Dockerfile, or maybe a small shell script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567475/docker-compose-check-if-mysql-connection-is-ready

Comment: I'm only using a Dockerfile, not docker-compose since the database it's not a multi-container app. But if this is the only possible solution I may have to consider it.

Comment: maybe adapt one of the shell script snippets in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503412/how-do-i-know-when-my-docker-mysql-container-is-up-and-mysql-is-ready-for-taking ?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the MariaDB docs on Docker Hub, it looks like there is a process built in for executing secondary scripts:

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
> the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
> configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
> extensions .sh, .sql, .sql.gz, and .sql.xz that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
> order. .sh files without file execute permission are sourced rather
> than executed. You can easily populate your mariadb services by
> mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with
> contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the
> database specified by the MARIADB_DATABASE / MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb

Answer (score 1):

You could add the command as a CMD line:

```
FROM mariadb:10.5.6

# Copy a "creation.sql" script to the container
COPY /sql/* /sql/

CMD mysql -e "source sql/creation.sql;" -uroot -pMyPasswordHere
```

You can also call CMD from a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service:
    ...
    command: 'command-to-start'
```

You may need to add a line in there to make it sleep for a while to ensure the process starts ok before your script runs. You could put it in a script, but if need be could include it in the CMD line as the first command followed by your script: `CMD first-command-to-sleep && second-command`.

If you find the CMD option is preventing MariaDB from starting, you may need to add in your own request for the process to start. A look at their Dockerfile (https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/10.5/Dockerfile) suggests it is:

```
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

So you would have `CMD first-command & second-command & mysqld`

`&` will make both run at the same time, whereas `&&` will wait for the first to finish successfully before running: [Can a bash script run simultaneous commands then wait for them to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993655/can-a-bash-script-run-simultaneous-commands-then-wait-for-them-to-complete)

This will execute as a shell process though, rather than exec which has some disadvantages: https://til.codes/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/

Other options include putting all that into a shell script, and calling it on launch: `CMD ["start.sh"]`. Here you would make sure that the last command mysqld is executed as `exec mysqld` which then ensures it is the main process executed and like running `CMD ["mysqld"]`.

Or using a service like SupervisorD if you wanted to make your own service container: http://supervisord.org

Or give each process its own container. Leaving the standard MariaDB container alone, then run a container with a script to call commands or execute custom processes. This of course will all depend on what it is you are trying to do and how much interaction you need with the contents of the container. If calling a docker container command, you could mount the docker socket into your container, install docker and then be able to execute the `docker exec -it my_container_name mysql -e "source sql/creation.sql;" -uroot -pMyPasswordHere` command from within it:  [Access Docker socket within container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135897/access-docker-socket-within-container). This may be a good option if you see there is a need to build a supervisor container that does lots of custom processes across your app.

As always, there are many ways to go about this. I would start by trying:

```
CMD mysql -e "source sql/creation.sql;" -uroot -pMyPasswordHere
```

If mariadb doesn't start because it has overridden the default CMD process, then would probably explore the start.sh solution.

I'm not familiar with MariaDB, but I would also explore whether command you are trying to run can be passed on as a config file or appended to the start command: `mysqld --variable --etc.`: https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/

Comment: Excellent, in-depth answer ... but unfortunately I've had no luck. I tried `CMD` with a script with a loop and sleep, various commands with `&&`, etc. Any error with `CMD` seems to silently stop the container, and I believe there are permission complications with running `mysqld`. Things like Docker sockets and SupervisorD are too far in the deep end for me right now.

Comment: Can you share the full code for the method you have chosen you want to pursue so that we can try and replicate it?

Comment: I added more details on my attempts to the original question

Comment: CMD mysqld && mysql -e "source sql/creation.sql;" -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD <-- this will wait until mysqld exits before continuing. And mysqld will never exit as per design. You would need '&' instead of '&&' to tell it to call both together (making sure the script sleeps on start if needed to ensure mysqld is up first).

The example shell script Dockerfile probably needs working directory to find the script. So would add the line: WORKDIR /scripts/ and CMD ["./start.sh"].

Comment: In the shell script, exec mysqld is likely stopping the rest of the script from running. You would need to be running command simultaneously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script

Answer (score 0):

I want to add the few other alternative ways to run queries inside the already run container

- Run from file

```bash
docker exec -i <Your_container_name> sh -c 'exec mariadb -uroot -p"$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD" <Your_DB_name>' < ./your_sql_file.sql
```

- Run a query/ies from command line.
  I run a Create table and grant privileges, but you can replace it with any query that you have in mind.

```bash
docker exec -i <your_container_name> sh -c 'exec echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS tp_old;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'some_user';" | mariadb -uroot -p"$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD"'
```

PS. My example is for mariadb, but it should equally work for mysql as well.